# ¿Por qué mi llamada a firebase se queda estancada y no avanza?

Tags: android, kotlin, realtime-database, android-corrutinas, firebase-snapshot

Estoy intentando leer un dato de firebase realtime database. Ademas estoy intentando que esa lectura sea síncrona.
Para lograrlo estoy implementado `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`

El método que hace la consulta a firebase es el siguiente:

```
suspend fun getData(): String{
    Log.v("Run", "Ejecutando getData()")
    var value = "0"
        try {
            value = quantityCharactersReference.get().await().toString()
        } catch(e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    return value
}
```

El método que invoca al anterior es el siguiente (ambos en la misma clase):

```
fun getPrefix(): String = runBlocking {
    Log.v("Prefix", "Antes de llamar a getData()")
    var data = getData()
    Log.v("Prefix", "Despues de llamar a getData()")

    return@runBlocking data
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando se ejecuta `getData()`, este se queda "atascado" en la linea

```
value = quantityCharactersReference.get().await().toString()
```

por lo tanto no continua con el proceso.

La version de `coroutines-play-services` que estoy usando es la 1.4.1

La variable `quantityCharactersReference` se forma de la siguiente manera:

```
private val quantityCharactersReference: DatabaseReference
    get() = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child("data")
        .child("first")
        .child("settings")
        .child("quantity")
        .child("lastGenerated")
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay nada malo con la librería `coroutines-play-services`. El problema es que usaste `runBlocking` que es sólo para testing o pequeñas demos.

**Nunca** debes usarlo en código de producción porque, como su nombre lo indica, bloquea el thread hasta que la tarea se completa. Esto **elimina todas las ventajas de usar corrutinas** y además la implementación que tiene en android hace que el main thread se bloquee para siempre. La explicación detrás de esto es compleja pero si te interesa puedes leer [este post](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-deadlock-your-android-app-with-runblocking-8dab02c2624d).

Veo que intentas usarlo para hacer que una función normal retorne el resultado de una suspend function, incluso cuando en tu pregunta anterior se te dijo que no lo hicieras. No puedo recomendarte una solución apropiada sin conocer tu use case pero  funcionará si haces que `getPrefix()` sea una suspend function

```
suspend fun getPrefix(): String {
    Log.v("Prefix", "Antes de llamar a getData()")
    var data = getData()
    Log.v("Prefix", "Despues de llamar a getData()")
    return data
}
```

En fin, tu llamada a firebase se estanca por usar `runBlocking` y para tu pregunta

> ¿Alguien tiene idea de qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

la respuesta más acertada es "Intentar traer datos de un servidor de forma síncrona". Si hacer eso tuviera sentido, el mismo SDK de Firebase tendría un método para hacerlo.

Si tienes problemas diseñando tu arquitectura, deberías leer la [guía de arquitectura](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) así como las [Prácticas recomendadas para corrutinas en Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices).

Comment: Muy bien, agradezco mucho tu respuesta y tú recomendación. Lamentablemente no puedo modificar la arquitectura y por ello no puedo aplicar lo que me recomendaron en la pregunta anterior. Más allá de eso, voy a probar lo que me pasaste, leer más al respecto e intentar plantear otra solución a ver si me la aprueban. Otra vez gracias por las respuestas.